# Symfony 2 registering a doctrine listener not working

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Services.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

    <container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">  

        <services>
            <service id="task.task_history_insertion" class="Acme\Bundle\EventListener\TaskHistoryInsertion">
                <argument type="service" id="service_container" />
                <tag name="doctrine.event_listener" event="postPersist" method="postPersist"/>
            </service>
        </services>
    </container>
```

TaskHistoryInsertion.php

```
class TaskHistoryInsertion implements EventSubscriber
{

    protected $container;
public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
{
    $this->container = $container; 
}

public function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return array(
        Event::postPersist
    );
}

public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
         //not being called
        }
}
```

Any ideas on why postPersist isn't being called after persisting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing event subscriber and event listener!

I would go for a event listener:

Remove

```
implements EventSubscriber
```

and

```
public function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return array(
        Event::postPersist
    );
}
```

Make sure you use

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
```

and that the services.xml gets loaded in src/Acme/Bundle/DependencyInjection/AcmeExtension.php.

Clear the cache and it should work.

The official documentation can be found at
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html

Comment: just for your information: any subscriber is also a valid listener - see https://github.com/doctrine/common/blob/2.3.0/lib/Doctrine/Common/EventManager.php#L126-L135

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you use the right **tag** for your service. You need to use `doctrine.event_subscriber` :

```xml
<service id="task.task_history_insertion" class="Acme\Bundle\EventListener\TaskHistoryInsertion">
    <argument type="service" id="service_container" />
    <tag name="doctrine.event_subscriber"/>
</service>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to implement eventListener - you should name the method in your listener class exactly like an event. In your example - you should have public method called postPersist. And the listener class shouldn't implement EventSubscriber.
There is a link that can give you much clearer picture about this topic http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/events.html

Comment: please don't reference `2.0.x` docs. Use `latest` instead: docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer :) I just wanted to make you aware of the fact that you should always reference the latest doc. That helps a lot!